# Sometime WCF service stop working all sudden and start returning 400

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, endpoint, http-status-code-400

We have a WCF service hosted on the IIS server which contains different OperationContracts. Most of the time all the OperationContracts work fine. But sometimes all of a sudden it stop working and start returning 400 server errors. There are 5 to 6 different caller system that is accessing the WCF service and all the systems get the same 400 error once issues start.

At the time of the issue, the application pool is up and running, the server CPU and Ram are normal, and the .svc endpoint also works fine inside and outside of the server. But the service caller receives 400 server errors when they try to access any of the WCF OperationContract.

At the start of every method, we logged the message in a log file for troubleshooting, and all the logs get logged successfully, it gets logged even when the caller gets the 400 server error. But once the hit comes to any methods somewhere in between it creates a problem and starts returning 400 server errors. Once we recycle or restart the application pool, it starts working normally.

WCF trace is already enabled for Critical, Error, and Warning switch values. But I can't find anything useful findings in the WCF trace files for this issue and I am new to WCF so it getting hard for me to understand the WCF trace files as well.

Can someone help us with where we should start troubleshooting and what are the ways to identify the root cause of the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Since the trace can contain confidential information and indeed it is hard to understand for beginners, you should open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com or hire an experienced consultant.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.